# Sign in with Google SDK - prompt=consent is forced

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I'm using the "[Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library for websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference)".
I'm using the `authorization code` model with `ux_mode=redirect`.

This is how my code looks like:

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: 'MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  ux_mode: 'redirect',
  redirect_uri: 'https://my.domain/google_redirect',
  scope: 'openid profile email'
});

client.requestCode();
```

However, I've noticed that the `prompt=consent` query string parameter is automatically added to the URL when the user is redirected to Google. Even when I attempt to override the `prompt` parameter in the `initCodeClient` call, the SDK ignores this and defaults to `consent`.

As a result, users are required to go through the consent dialog every time they sign in, even though they have previously granted consent.

What should I do to avoid showing the user the consent dialog after the first login?

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting only request only the identity scope (`openid profile email`), it would be easier to use the [Sign in with Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) library instead.

Thanks,
Herman